# Is there a way to launch userscripts directly from browser (Firefox)?

Tags: firefox, tampermonkey, userscripts

I would like to run some userscripts to backup data.

- The same scripts could be used on a variety of websites.
- Scripts are basically the same, only some configuration changes from one script to another (what to scrape on the page, and where to save it).
- Scripts will not alter the page in any way, just read it then call some REST API with the data

I do not want these scripts to be loaded on every web page, as they won't alter them, and depending on the page there is only one I'd like to run anyway.

---

So is there a way to launch these scripts directly from the browser (Firefox) ? From a bookmark or something ? Basically I want to click a button and have the script run like if I was running it from the js console.

---

Best I found for now is the "@run-at context-menu" directive of Tampermonkey. My script appears in a TamperMonkey context menu and is run on click.

However this menu is loaded on every page (@run-at context-menu ignores the @include directive and is applied everywhere), I'm not sure of the performance consequences, and it might be inconvenient if I end up with lots of scripts.

---

I guess I could also modify my scripts to be run on specific pages so that they add a floating button or something. But I'd rather not modify the pages, and it would be inconvenient on pages where I'd like to have several possible scripts.

---

I remember using a Greasemonkey script that added options on the context menu a long while ago. Would that be possible with Tampermonkey, implementing an equivalent of the @run-at context-menu myself that would only work on some pages ?

---

A more native way would be best, but I'm open to options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a function for that: https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.registerMenuCommand

Your script just needs to declare a function, call GM.registerMenuCommand("label", your_function), and it becomes available on click in the GM/TM menu.

Contrary to the other answer this means you can use @require.

Contrary to the @run-at context-menu this means you can use @match to only apply it to the intended websites

Notes:
GM_registerMenuCommand in TamperMonkey
Needs the @grant to use the function

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I want to click a button and have the script run like if I was running it from the js console.

From above, I assume the userscript does not use any GM API or use `@require` since those are not available in JS console.

If that is the case, [FireMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemonkey/) has a feature to inject script (or CSS) from the toolbar popup.

After saving a script and disabling it (so it doesn't run automatically) or enabling on sites that the script MUST run, users can select the script in the toolbar icon popup and click the button to inject the script in the active tab.

For temporary scripts, FireMonkey also has a Scratchpad that you can paste JS (or CSS) into and run on any webpage by clicking the button. FireMonkey remembers the last pasted data so that it can be reused.

***Note:** Except TM that alters the CSP of websites, other managers are bound by the webpage CSP.*